# Is socket over bluetooth eavesdropping proof?

Tags: security, bluetooth

I am sending sensitive data through socket connection over Bluetooth, no pairing involved. The environment is windows mobile 6, Microsoft BT stack, DOTNET CF. Some article I've read suggested that the data link layer handles encryption before L2CAP layer connection is established but I am not sure how does MS BT Stack communicate with these layers and if it takes care of encryption automatically.

Any idea is deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing is "eavesdropping proof" - there's just different degrees of how difficult it is and how hard it is to extract real data from what is eavesdropped.

Comment: I understood that. I guess my question was that, whether packages in the air are encrypted or just plain binary representation of protocols and data (if MS BT Stack and socket are used in communication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my neophyte knowledge of the Bluetooth stack I would say there is no encryption on your link.

My reasoning: If your not entering any pin codes or pairing the devices then that implies that either your device is using mode 0 - no security or mode 2 with no security on the service you are using for the link (RFCOMM I assume?). No security == no encryption (I am reasonably informed).